# How can I detect the maximum refresh-rate output of the VGA card?

Tags: graphics-card, refresh-rate

I just want to buy a new monitor with a refresh-rate 144Hz, and use it with my old card MSI GTX 1050Ti.

So my question is: how can I know my VGA card can output with 144Hz, even I don't play a game. For Example: watch Youtube.

There is a document on Nvidia Official Site for refresh-rate but seem nothing for GTX 1050ti. But I can find for 2060 Spec as [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-in/geforce/graphics-cards/rtx-2060-super/)
`1 - 4k 12-bit HDR at 144Hz or 8k 12-bit HDR at 60Hz over one DisplayPort 1.4 connector (with DSC).` 
Do you know how to detect the output refresh-rate? Of couse, I must use the right connector for maximum refresh rate.

Comment: "Graphics card specifications may vary by Add-in-card manufacturer" Nvidia does not manufacture the cards, they only design the chip. Who made your card?

Comment: My card is MSI GTX 1050Ti

Comment: Only thing I can suggest is to run video card benchmarking software.>>>https://www.gpumag.com/best-gpu-benchmarking-software/